# Unable to create shader debug session

Tags: xcode, debugging, shader, metal

Update the Xcode to 12beat, it doesn't work for metal frame debugger.The error is as follows：
DYPShaderDebuggerErrorDomain:2
"Could not generate shader metadata."
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

By manual compiling remember to add `-gline-tables-only -MO -g` arguments to *.air compiling process.

Comment: The phrasing of this confusingly alternated between "me too", clarifcation question and something which actually looks like an answer. I have edited to reduce to the answering part. Please [edit] to make sure that the answer is an answer (I don't want you to suffer from misunderstanding caused by the answering part standalone does not make sense).